# Naphthalene v/s Anthracene reactivity

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, resonance, reactivity

Both have similar resonance energy per ring, even Naphthalene has a little higher Resonance energy (127.5 KJ per mol per ring v/s 127 KJ per mol per ring )

Can we prove , why there is a small difference between them and Anthracene has lower resonance energy ?

Is there significant difference in their reactivity ?

Comment: In naphthalene, both rings are similar. In anthracene, the middle one is significantly different ("less aromatic") from the other two, hence the reactivity.